# SQL Error on view

Tags: views, database

There is a Drupal view, replacing the normal page at /admin/content. It throws an error on the view page which goes away after you clear the cache, and then comes back.

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'LEFT JOIN taxonomy_index taxonomy_index ON node.nid = taxonomy_index.nid LEFT JO' at line 2
```

Cant seem to figure out what the issue is.

Answer (score 0):

I would need more information to help, but I would suggest updating both views and taxonomy modules to their most recent stable version first, to see if this resolves your issue. If this does not, then try the latest dev version of each module (as always, back up your db first).